# Bounding quantiles of the noncentral chi distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, approximation-theory, lower-bounds

I need to bound the empirical quantiles for a [*noncentral* chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution) (not chi-squared) $\chi_\nu(\lambda)$, where $\nu$ is the number of degrees of freedom and $\lambda$ the non-centrality parameter.

In case it helps; I can make the following assumptions:

- $5000>\nu>50$
- $\lambda \in [\frac{\sqrt{\nu-1}}{2}-2,\frac{\sqrt{\nu-1}}{2}+2]$
- number of samples $10^2<n<10^4$
- Interested in q-quantile and (1-q)-quantile for $q\in[0.01,0.05]$

My current approach involves getting bounds on the theoretical quantiles and applying Chernoff to get bounds on empirical quantiles given enough samples.

The closest thing I've found is [Approximations to the Non-Central Chi-Squared Distribution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333761). Note it's for [Non-central Chi-Squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution), not Non-central Chi. Modifying the math in the paper a bit (setting b=0 in its initial formula) gives me a Gaussian approximation for non-central chi with approximate cumulants; but I'm not sure if this is a promissing approach since this is far from my normal research area.

Is there a better approach to bound the theoretical quantiles of the non-central chi-squared than by trying to approximate it with a Gaussian?

Comment: How big is your sample size $n$? If $(1-q)$-quantiles are the ones of interest, what is the range of the values of $q$? Do you want asymptotic or non-asymptotic bounds?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I've added two extra assumptions refering to q and n; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I think you can use the fact that, if $X$ is a nonnegative random variable and $x_q$ is its $(1-q)$-quantile, then $x_q^2$ is a $(1-q)$-quantile of $X^2$, and vice versa. Thus, you reduce your noncentral chi distribution to the known case of a noncentral chi-squared distribution.